# Loaded r packages yesterday. Now getting error messages

Tags: r

Can't use the GUI to import datasets and certain packages will not load. I get this message. I'm stumped.

```
library(likert)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘tibble’
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

Comment: `there is no package called ‘tibble’` - install it first I'm guessing.

Comment: If that still doesn't work after installing `tibble`, potentially specify the `dependencies = T` argument when running the `install.packages` function again. By setting the argument to `T`, the function will determine "...whether to also install uninstalled packages which these packages depend on/link to/import/suggest..."